# confused with boolean and comparison instructions

Tags: assembly, x86, boolean, flags

I am trying to set the zero flag if the signed integer in EAX (32 bit) is even and greater than 100, otherwise clear zero flag.

This is what I have so far:

```
TEST EAX, 1 ; test to see if number is even - sets ZF if even
CMP EAX, 100 ; compares eax with 100
```

For `cmp eax, 100` the problem is that if eax is greater than 100 it will clear the zero flag, rather than set it. How do I set the zero flag, if EAX is greater than 100?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are instructions which affects the flags. Not just the Zero Flag, but others as well, depending ont heir design. If you have consecuticve instructions affecting the same flag, as in your exmaple, then the flag will always reflect the status of the last instruction. In your case the result of `test eax, 1` is lost.

If you need multiple tests then you must usually branch to some code, which will handle it, and then continue. An alternative way could be to store the flags with a `pushf; pop eax` and handle it later.

```
 test eax, 1
 je doSomething
 cmp eax, 100
 je doSomethingElse
```

In case of the zero flag, there is also an instruction which can set the state into a register:

```
 test eax, 1
 setz bl
```

To see which flags are affected by individual instructions, you should download the Intel Developer Manual Volume 3.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you don't. Flags are, as a general rule, overwritten (but sometimes only partially, eg `dec` doesn't affect the carry flag) rather than combined. You could materialize the boolean with `setcc` and do this sort of thing:

```
test eax, 1
setz dl
cmp eax, 100
setg dh
and dl, dh
jnz somewhere  ; will go there if eax was even and greater than 100
```

It's a little simpler to just use two branches:

```
test eax, 1
jnz odd      ; go away if eax is odd
cmp eax, 100
jg somewhere
```